# Send username and password from Application A to Application B

Tags: java, reactjs, rest, authentication, jwt

I have Application A which have login screen. Once I successfully logged into Application A, I need to access application B by sharing username and password in post request.

Application B is developed using ReactJs as frontend and Spring Boot REST API as backend.

I have JWT authentication in Application B. How to get the username and password in client browser and invoke authentication service. Is there a way to achieve this.

Comment: Instead why not just have both applications use the same token authentication from a single database for example? It's never a good idea to share plain-text passwords.

Comment: There is no way you can get the something in the browser of client of application B. 
Application B doesn't know anything about login that happened in Application A. 

What you need to focus is follow some OAuth2 Standard where Application B will reqeust a authentication flow which will either be verified by Application A or other third party as well. 

However @jason has also suggested wonderful Idea